# Rotation of a part of a 3d Model of a Laptop with Three.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a 3d model of a laptop in the form of a .gltf file. It consists of 2 parts (nodes):

1. Base
2. Lid

I want to rotate the lid around the base, anchoring the lid to the top of the base of the laptop. This would give an effect of the laptop opening or closing.

The animation synchronizes with the user's scroll behavior.

I am working in a next.js app. Following is my code snippet.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, Suspense } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Environment, PerspectiveCamera, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Home() {
  function Model(props: any) {
    const groupRef = useRef<THREE.Group>(null!);
    const lidGroupRef = useRef<THREE.Group>(null!);
    const lidRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);

    const nodesModel = useRef('model_0Mesh1');
    const { nodes, materials, ...prop } = useGLTF('/assets/3d/Macbook2.gltf') as any
    const scrollDown = () => {
  lidGroupRef.current.rotation.x += 0.1

}
const scrollUp = () => {
  lidGroupRef.current.rotation.x -= 0.1
}
    useEffect(() => {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      const handleWheel = (event: any) => {
        console.log(event.deltaY, event);
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
          // Scrolling down
          scrollDown();

        } else {
          // Scrolling up
          scrollUp();
        }
      };

      window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
        document.body.style.overflow = '';
      };
    }, []);
    return (
      <group ref={groupRef} {...props}>
        <group ref={lidGroupRef} position={[95, -80, 0]} >
          <mesh ref={lidRef} position={[0, -23, -50]} rotation={[3, 0, 0]} scale={[6, 4, 2]} geometry={(nodes.Lid as THREE.Mesh).geometry} material={materials['lambert2']} />
        </group>
        <mesh position={[95, -80, 0]} rotation={[2.4, 0, 0]} scale={[6, 4, 2]} geometry={(nodes.Base as THREE.Mesh).geometry} material={materials['lambert2']} />
      </group>
    )
  }

  useGLTF.preload('/assets/3d/Macbook2.gltf')
  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }}>
      <Canvas style={{ background: 'white !important' }}>
        <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 0, 100]} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Model />
          <Environment preset="sunset" />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is the initial state of the 3d laptop model with lid half closed:

[image: Macbook2.gltf]